# Why do I get invalid data exception while reading an xml file in C#

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine, xmlreader

I am trying to read an xml file in Unity3D using this code

```
using (XmlReader xmlreader=XmlReader.Create("Assets\\config.xml")) 
{
    while (xmlreader.Read()) 
    {
        Debug.Log (xmlreader.Name.ToString());
    }
}
```

It prints all the names of the elements of the xml file except the last one. Because in the end it gives an invalid data exception. Why?

Comment: The date? It says invalid datA (not date).

Comment: Ah apologies; I misread it. :) In that case, you'll need to start sharing some of this data and the code as it could be absolutely any reason.

Comment: Agree with @DavidArno. You're going to have to dig in and get more information. That's a relatively generic exception. Explore its other properties, maybe there's more information there. Also take a look at the file in an editor that might tell you what's wrong (like Studio with Resharper installed).

Comment: Please delete this question as it serves no useful purpose to the wider community.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

I had to put this line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```

At the beginning of xml file.